# jQuery - passing arrays in post request

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django

I want to pass arrays in the jquery $.post() request.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="add-check-1e30">
<input type="checkbox" id="add-check-1230">
```

From the above example HTML the array should be like this = ['1e30', '1230']

jQuery for sending $.post():

```
$("#addbox-add").click(function(){

var ukeys = new Array();
$("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each( function() {
a = $(this).attr("id");
b = a.split('-').pop();
ukeys.push(b);
});

$(".addbox").remove();

$.post("/information/portfolio/add/", {'ukeys': ukeys }, function(data) {
for(i=0; i<data.length; i++)
{
    ukey = data[i].ukey;
    image = data[i].image;
    service = data[i].service;
    if(data[i].smallimage != "")
    {
        image = data[i].smallimage;
    }
    if (image == null)
    {
        $(".portfolio-preview").append('<li class="portfolio-item" id="portfolio-item-'+service+'-'+ukey+'"></li>');
    }
    else
    {
        $(".portfolio-preview").append('<li class="portfolio-item" id="portfolio-item-'+service+'-'+ukey+'"><img class="portfolio-image" src="'+image+'" width="150px" height="150px"></li>');
    }
}
});

});
```

There is no problem with the array variable in jQuery, I don't know how to send it in the post request.

I'm supposed to get those two values **1e30 and 1230** in the server. But the values I'm getting in the server is null.

Here is the server code for fetching the values in Python/Django:

```
def portfolio_add(request):
    ukeys = request.POST.get('ukeys', '')   
    .....etc.....etc......
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please cut down your code to the relevant bit. In that HTML for example, all those divs and spans are irrelevant and make it hard to find the actual interesting stuff, ie the checkboxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use:

```
request.POST.getlist('ukeys', '')
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: `getlist() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)`

Comment: Sorry, request.POST.getlist('ukeys')

Comment: Still I'm getting no values in the server side.

Comment: `def portfolio_add(request):
        ukeys = request.POST.getlist('ukeys')
        return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(ukeys), mimetype='application/json')`

Comment: and I'm alerting the value in jQuery where I'm getting nothing.

Comment: Please print request.POST in your server. And paste here

Comment: `u'[]'` I'm getting empty list in the server.

Comment: please only print request.POST

Comment: `u"<QueryDict: {u'ukeys[]': [u'68c04', u'16149']}>"`

Comment: Ok then is easy. Your key is "ukeys[]". This is a problem to js. You can access from django request.POST.getlist('ukeys[]')