# django - getlist()

Tags: python, django

I just posted this question [jQuery - passing arrays in post request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189079/jquery-passing-arrays-in-post-request/), where I don't to send arrays in post request, but there is no problem in jQuery code.

The problem is with receiving the POST request in django. I did like this.

```
def portfolio_add(request):
    ukeys = request.POST.getlist('ukeys')
    ........etc.......
```

But I'm getting ukeys values as `u'[]'`. When I checked with just `request.POST` I got the values as `u"<QueryDict: {u'ukeys[]': [u'68c04', u'16149']}>"`

So, How to get those values as a list in Django?

Thanks!

Answer (score 103, accepted):

jQuery POST's arrays with the `[]` suffix because PHP and some web frameworks understand that convention, and re-build the array on the server-side for you automatically. Django doesn't work that way, but you should be able to access the data via:

```
ukeys = request.POST.getlist('ukeys[]')
```

Comment: is there an equivalent for `getlist` in js? I want to get the same data that is sent via post method also in that template in `<script>` tag

Comment: I've noticed that when I printed request.POST but I didn't know that this is jquery feature

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this same issue -- Jakub is right, the `[]` is useful for other web frameworks, but the behavior of jQuery can be changed (I didn't like the `varname[]` format).

The `$.param` function is specifically what does this and it also accepts a parameter to override this behavior.

**Change Globally:**

```
// put this early in your JS, preferably the first one imported after jQuery
//     or before the document.ready function if using inline js
jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;
```

**Change on a per-call basis:**

```
 $.param(data, true);  // true sets traditional mode
// for example:
 $.post('/some/url/', $.param(data, true)).done(callback)
```

Or of course you can use the `[]` on the server as Jakub mentions.