# jQuery POST not returning variable users

Tags: jquery, django, jquery-post

I am trying to post the values of checked boxes, but unable to do so. It first collects all the checked boxes in an array (`selected_users`-which is working fine upon testing it with `alert` function )and then sends them collectively. But I'm not able to post the data. The error that I get is Key 'users' not found in . Where i'm going wrong? how do I modify my POST statement in jQuery plugin?

**View.py**

def get_data(request):

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
    selected_users = request.POST['users']
return HttpResponse(selected_users)
```

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'get_data/','apps.api.views.get_data', name = 'grabhalo_get_data'),
)
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $('#submit').click(function() {
                  var selected_users = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, el) {
                    return $(el).val();
                    }).get();
                    alert(selected_users);     // works fine
                    $.post("get_data/",{users:selected_users});   // not able to post
                });    
            })
```

**Checkboxes**

```
{% for user in users %}
    <input type="checkbox" class="check" value="{{user.id}}" />{{user.name}}<br>    
{%endfor%}

    <form id="form" method="POST" action="/get_data/">
       {% csrf_token %}
       <input type="text" class="span8 search-query" placeholder="Type here..." name="chat">
       <input type="submit" value="Send" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "submit">
   </form>
```

Different Suggestions are welcomed , if anyone can redefine the .post function.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your JQuery $.post function is ok, the problem is getting the values in a Django view. You are posting an array of values - to get them you use `getlist()` function on POST QueryDict. So your view would look like this:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_users = request.POST.getlist('users[]')
    return HttpResponse(selected_users)
```

Please see:

[QueryDict.getlist(key, default)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist)

[django - getlist()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190070/django-getlist)

Comment: well the error has been removed, but now I am getting `None` upon `print selected_users`

Comment: it prints an empty list

Comment: I've tried your code and it actually posts checkbox values, please check your POST request with DevTools and look at actual in request contents in the Network tab.

Comment: Try this with your original jquery code that you wrote in your question.

Comment: Well, I tried but I'm not able to get the output. I used console.log(selected_users) and it does shows the checked boxes list, but I'm not able to fetch it to the views.py file

Comment: hi Yuriy, I'm still not able to get the desired output. Can you post your code when you tried running it. Thanks

Comment: Yes, sure. Here is code in [gist on github](https://gist.github.com/Walkeryr/6152056)

Comment: Thanks for replying @yuriy.  I have a query that why did you not provided any url in the `$.post("", {users: selected_users});` and also left blank in urls.py? Though I'm still not able to get any results.

Comment: Hm, probably we are using different versions of JQuery, I'm using JQuery 2.0.3. I thought if you don't specify url, it makes POST to the same url from which POST is initiated. Can you post your full code in gist, too?

Comment: [Here is the link](https://gist.github.com/prafulbagai/6154196). Kindly look into the same. Thanks

Comment: Well I have tried posting simple values as well, But its still not able to fetch the data. I'm using chrome browser.

Comment: I guess you need to use debug to investigate your problem. Use Google Chrome Web Inspector to debug javascript code and see POST request in Network section. Also try to debug python code in some IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you try your POST like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#submit').click(function() {
      var selected_users=[];
      var $inputs = $('.check');
      $inputs.each(function() {         
            selected_users.push( $(this).val());        
        });            
                    alert(selected_users);     // works fine
      $.post("get_data/",{"users" : selected_users},function(response) 
        {
            alert(response);
        });     
            })
```

try this in your view.py :

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
selected_users = request.POST.get("selected_users", "")
return HttpResponse(selected_users)
```

Comment: Just to make the storing of variables in array clearer, no other purpose.. :)

Comment: I edited my views.py as @yuriy said and tried your jQuery statements as well but it prints an empty list. Any idea why?

Comment: Can you console.log(selected_users) and check if your not sending an empty array? I hope you've done that already?

Comment: No, I haven't done that earlier. But,upon submitting the button, it prints nothing in the console.

Comment: Well, now I am able to get the console.log output. But still not able to post the data. :(

Comment: What are you able to see in firebug POST request?

Comment: Well, I'm able to see the `selected_users` in console.log but it refreshes immediately and console.log clears out. So, I'm not able to see in the POST request

Comment: Can we continue the conversation in the chat?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34794/discussion-between-aditya-and-user1162512)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to combined @Aditya and @Yurly answers:

**script**

```
function get_csrf_token(){
    return $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val();
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {
        var datas = new Array();
        var i = 0;
        var csrf_token = get_csrf_token();

        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function() {
            datas[i] = $(this).val();
            i++;
        });   

        #make sure the url is correct
        $.post("get_data/", {'users[]': datas, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': csrf_token}, function(data){
            alert(data);
        });   
    });    
})
```

**views.py**

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    selected_users = request.POST.getlist('users[]')
    return HttpResponse(selected_users)
```

Comment: And question, why you put your input checkbox outside in the form?

Comment: And to answer your query, checkbox are in different divs. So, I need them to be outside the form as per my requirements.

Comment: I'm getting an empty list. Any suggestions WHY?

Comment: are you sure your url is correct? Isn't an app name there? about your checkbox, even though it's in different divs you must put it inside the form

Comment: Hi Catherine, the url is correct. Please have a look at [this link](https://gist.github.com/prafulbagai/6154196) and help me rectify it. Thanks!!

Comment: Ok the problem is you don't pass the crsf token which POST won't allow it if there is no detected.

Comment: Another thing is you can put them both inside the form. Just put the form head above `div span6` then the form close is in the bottom of `div span10`

Comment: Yes. I had tried what you posted in the last comment earlier, and yes I was successful, but for that I dont need the jquery script. I just used `selected_users = request.POST.getlist('users') & query = request.POST['query']` and I was able to get the data. jQuery has nothing to do with it. What I want it to be implemented it with jQuery because I need more functionalities which can be completed with jQuery. Any idea. Where I 'm going wrong?

Comment: Will now try your `csrf` soluton.

Comment: I tried your `csrf` solution as well, by removing the `csrf_token`, it shows `403 forbidden error` saying `csrf token missing`. Upon commenting `'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',` in the settings.py file, the error has been removed but it does not shows the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

When you submit the form you would need to prevent the default action. Otherwise your page refreshes voiding an post from happening.

Also use serialize array to convert them into an array. Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#submit').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         // Will only serialize the checked values by default
         var selected_users = $('input[type=checkbox]').serializeArray();
          console.log(selected_users);     
          $.post("get_data/",{'users[]':selected_users}); 
     });    
})
```

You can use `$.ajax` instead if you want to work with lot more options

```
$.ajax({
     url : 'get_data', 
     data : {'users[]' : selected_users},
     dataType: "set it to the type you are expecting".
     type : 'post'
}).done(function(data, status, xhr) {
   console.log(data)
}).fail(function(xhr, status, error) {
   console.log("Error status : "+ status + "-- error : " + error);
});
```

Comment: Well, I have already tried both the methods. In the first one, it says `403-forbidden csrf termination`  and the second one doesnt works. I'm just getting an empty list, though console.log shows the parameters passed.
Any idea whats wrong?

Comment: Check the request in the Network tab of the Developer tools in chrome.. And see how the params and headers look like

Comment: the parameters are like ["1","2"].

Comment: I want to fetch these parameters as a list in the backend.

Comment: I am not able to get the posted variable in the `views.py` file.

Comment: Are you selecting using `selected_users = request.POST['users[0]']`

Comment: No. I'm using [0] index for collecting the variable. Istead I'm just using `users`. Tried with `users[]` as well, but no luck

Comment: **I'm not using [0]. Sorry typo.

Comment: Why don't you send a single value and see what happens... `var val = 5; $.post("get_data/",{'users':val}); ` Check if you are able to access it

Comment: Well have tried that as well. But not getting the single value as well. Just to confirm while passing single value should I use `selected_users = request.POST.getlist('users')` or `selected_users = request.POST.get('users')`, although tried with both.

Comment: `if request.method == 'POST':
    for k in request.POST:
        print(k)

    selected_users = request.POST.getlist('users')
    return HttpResponse(selected_users)`

I have tried this as well. It only prints the keys of form, not the checkbox values stored in `users` variable.

Comment: I am not much of a php guy.. you might be missing something really small

Comment: Did you try sending a normal variable instead of an array?

Comment: Yes. As said earlier tried with single value as well, but no luck. Trying it from last 2 days and still stuck up on this only.

Comment: No. Whats this? I'm unaware of this. And can we continue our conversation in chat?

Comment: Tried. Still not getting.

Comment: Well, is there any other way og doing this, other than jQuery or Ajax, because I'm on tight deadline?

Comment: Difficult to say wht exactly is happening unless you debug.. Can you get a screen shot of how the request looks like in dev tools

Comment: Can we do it on Team Viewer, if you are comfortable with it?

Comment: I don't have it installed currently.. I just anted something like this http://imgur.com/50HzHQZ  .. Just wanna have a look at the request and the headers

Comment: Phewww.... Yes, now I'm able to achieve it, but its kind of not acceptable. I actually put the checkboxes inside the form and it worked. BUT, when I keep it outside the the form, it does not works. Any idea why?

Comment: Anyways Thanx Sushant. SUPRABHATAM :P P

Comment: Glad to have been of help :)