# High Charts not working

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I followed [this link](http://jsfiddle.net/highcharts/kh5jY/) to draw the bar graphs using HighCharts Charting library.

It works on `jsfiddle` but when I try to build a HTML file out of this code, it does not shows any thing.

Here is my html file.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7/prototype.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/adapters/prototype-adapter.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                    $('#container').highcharts({
                        chart: {
                            type: 'bar'
                        },
                        title: {
                            text: 'Fruit Consumption'
                        },
                        xAxis: {
                            categories: ['Apples', 'Bananas', 'Oranges']
                        },
                        yAxis: {
                            title: {
                                text: 'Fruit eaten'
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                            name: 'Jane',
                            data: [1, 0, 4]
                        }, {
                            name: 'John',
                            data: [5, 7, 3]
                        },
                                 {
                            name: 'RAHUL',
                            data: [1, 5, 4]
                        }],
                    });
                });

        </script>
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="container" style="height: 300px"></div>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because you seem to be using a `jQuery selector`  **$('#container')**

**And not including jQuery in your page**

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/FDjq7/)**

This works as we are including jQuery as a framework.

Include

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

before your highCharts library and it should work fine.

Comment: @Sushanth - if you kindly look into [this link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18043753/jquery-post-not-returning-variable-users/18043776?noredirect=1#comment26404998_18043776) and provide some help in this context as well. I'll be highly oblidged. Thanks

Comment: Glad to have helped :)

Answer (score 0):

you are including highcharts.js two times.

remove the last occurence of it inside the body tag.

Comment: I was just testing with that. I didnt got any output even after removing it.