# Sending a javascript array to django views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, django

I have the following javascript array at the client side -

```
["27", "28", "29", "30"]
```

I am sending it to server as follows -

```
$.post(
  '/save/mempks/1/',
  {'data':elmArry},
  function(data){alert(data);});
```

On the server, I have put a debugger to see how, the data is received, and I see this unusual behaviour -

```
ipdb> request.POST
<QueryDict: {u'data[]': [u'27', u'28', u'29', u'30']}>

ipdb> request.POST.items()
[(u'data[]', u'30')]

ipdb> request.POST['data[]']
u'30'
```

All I want to do is extract, the numbers 27 to 30 and save it in a list.

Where are the numbers 27, 28, 29, and 30 are getting lost?

Could anyone suggest, why this behavior?

Comment: possible duplicate of [django - getlist()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190070/django-getlist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in case of posting list use request.POST.getlist('key') to get data. If you would use some kind of form for picking up posted data, then it would do it for you. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#id3