# How to get a list of checkboxes from html form in django

Tags: python, django, html, forms, django-forms

So I want to get a list of checkboxes values with a form. 
My form looks liek this :

```
<form action=/test>
<ul style="font-size:30px">
    {% for d in Dlist %}
        <li type="none"><input type="checkbox" name="dl" value={{d.name}}>{{department.name }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
</form>
```

So I have a list of checkboxes each for an object in Dlist.

My request looks like that :

```
x=request.POST.getlist('dl')
```

It works and when I use x in the template I get a list, the problem is that the list does not contain the value each d , the x list contains values that looks like : u,uhd3h02283ddh.

I can`t write the exact values i get in the list right now (that`s also the reason my code ain`t full). So if the information I gave is enough to solve this please help me find what`s wrong and how to get the right vlaues.

Thanks.

Comment: Is that really your html? You've got the name attribute on the li, not the input, so you shouldn't be getting any results at all.

Comment: Adding the code defined in your view would help debug your problem.

Answer (score 0):

check this answer? [django - getlist()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190070/django-getlist)

so for you it would be:

```
x=request.POST.getlist('dl[]')
```