# Getting list values in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, post

I am posting values from the frontend using jQuery to django on the backend.

I use

```
list = request.POST
print list
```

which returns:

```
<QueryDict: {u'country': [u'test'], u'town_select[]': [u'town3', u'town4', u'town5']}>
```

I want to retrieve the `town_select[]` list but when I do

```
town = list.get('town_select[]')
```

and print it I only get the last town in the list `town5`. I want to get all three towns.

If anyone knows what I've done wrong it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use

```
town = request.POST.getlist('town_select')
```

or maybe

```
town = request.POST.getlist('town_select[]')
```

as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190070/django-getlist) suggests.

Comment: Thats great! Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `getlist` method on `request.POST`.

```
request.POST.getlist('town_select[]')
```