# Send table data from template to view.py in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I am passing a list i.e `data_code` from `view.py` to a html file and from there i am printing the data of the table using for loop through the list. There is a editable column in the table `<input>` and i want to get those data after filled by user on my `view.py`. so anybody any idea how to do that??

I want to get all `{{x.2}}` in `view.py`. It is printing some default value but i want it again after it is being by user.

Here is the code:

```
<table class="table table-bordered datatable">
    <thead class="table-head">
      <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>Code Point</th>
        <th>Reference</th>
        <th>Character</th>
        <th>Text</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for x in data_code %}
      <tr class="table-row">
        <td>{{ forloop.counter }}</td>
        <td><label>{{ x.0 }}</label></td>
        <td><input id="codepoint_input" type="text" value={{x.2}} size=3 title="Text"></td>
        <td><label> {{x.3}}</label></td>
        <td>{{x.4}}</td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Comment: look up django forms

Comment: @e4c5 can't you give me some hints on this?

Comment: that's what I have done

Comment: I read django forms but didn't get any good example. So it will be great if you can put some example on this.

Answer (score 1):

The first task is get those entered values using jquery simply...

```
$(#codepoint_input).keypress(function(e) {
    if(e.which == 13) {
        // your custom code here.
        var tablestring = $("#tableForm").serialize();

        $.post( "/backend", tablestring );

    }
});
```

Finally you can get the values in your view function...

```
def backend(request):
    print(request.POST)
```

Comment: will you please elaborate your code. Means what is `e.which==13` will do. And will it able to get all the values like if loop is run 10 times then there will be 10 input may be some are changed and some have default value? if yes will it will a list or what?

Comment: @tenstormavi see everytime user enters something ...  `keypress` getting fire and I'm tracking only the `Enter_Key` so if pressed then you can get the values right ?

Comment: If you want to get all the N th number of values and passing into views then I can help with that...

Comment: okay but I want all the values at the same time whether it is changed or default value. I have to further process all the values in my code. so how i can get all the 10 values at the same time @Raja Simon

Comment: Okay tell me how to do that? @Raja Simon

Comment: @tenstormavi you should wrap the table with form and something this code will help you. `var tablestring = $("#tableForm").serialize();` instead in if statement and you are good to go

Comment: And how will i receive the inputs in view.py? If possible give an example on this code please.

Comment: Did you tried it? And i am going to implement it on click function not keypress. And one more question if i want to print the input one by one then like `print(request.POST)` will print all the value at once.

Comment: @tenstormavi Okay keypress or `on.('click ` both will work. And you are missing something and you not telling me correctly what you want to achieve so I my assumption is not correct.

Comment: Do you know you can add `name="codepoint_input[]"` when multiple same name parameter ? so in your view function you can get that using [getlist](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11190754/3762142http://stackoverflow.com/a/11190754/3762142)

Comment: See the question, its a for loop under it there is a input field which have some value by default but it is editable so user can edit it. Now i want to take all the input from that input field whether it has the changed value given by user or the default value. And pass the whole things to view.py as a list or dictionary whatever it is, so that i can further process it. Understand?

Comment: Bdw the link you have given for getlist doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
Use dictionary type so that you can give each input box a unique name through the key, and use the corresponding value in value parm.

In view, you can use a for loop to go through the whole dictionary, and use the key to get the values from the template.

In your Template:

```
<form name = "yourForm" method="GET" action="/" class = "main">
{% for key, value in json.data_code%}
     <td>
        <input name = "{{ key }}" id="codepoint_input" type="text" value={{ value }} size=3 title="Text">
        <input type="submit" id = "amountbtn" style="visibility:hidden;" >

    </td>
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

In your views:

```
key1 = request.GET.get('key1') 
....
```

Comment: will it able to get all the values like if loop is run 10 times then there will be 10 input may be some are changed and some have default value? if yes will it will a list or what?

Comment: @tenstormavi Ahh, I see. I guess there will be x amount of rows with x amount of input boxes. In that case, I will make an edit.