# How to get array of values from checkbox form Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have HTML form like this:

```
    <p>Models Sizes IDs:</p>
    <input type="checkbox" name="model_size_ids[]" value="1">XS</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="model_size_ids[]" value="2">S</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="model_size_ids[]" value="3">M</input>
    <input type="checkbox" name="model_size_ids[]" value="4">L</input>
    <button>Submit</button>
```

I'm trying to receive an array of checked values on server side in my `View`:

```
size_ids = request.data['model_size_ids[]']
```

But, I can extract only one and the last value. So if I check 2-3 values in 
checkbox form, I receive only last value in my view. I also tried to name input field without braсkets and the result was the same. Can anybody tell me, how can I solve that?
Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django - getlist()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190070/django-getlist)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the getlist method for geting the list of selected choices

```
request.POST.getlist('model_size_ids[]')
```

Comment: Also note that you don't need the brackets ("[ ]") in the name for Django to correctly  treat this as a list (this bracket thing is a PHP hack actually, not a part of the HTTP spec)