# Django getlist getting null

Tags: javascript, django

Hello guys im currently learning on how to send data from HTML to Django backend using Ajax.

I have this HTML

```
<div class="form-row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="car-checkbox[]" value="Audi" id="chck1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="car-checkbox[]" value="BMW" id="chck2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="car-checkbox[]" value="Lambo" id="chck2">
    <input id="submit-car" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
```

and then to send the data i use this code (Ajax)

```
$('#submit-car').click(function () {
    const data = {user_id: user_id}

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/submit-car/',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#submit-form-field').prop('disabled', true);
            location.reload();
            alert("Submit OK!");
        }
    });
});
```

and then on the Django side i try to get the checked checkbox

```
def insert_car_to_db(self, request):
   cars = request.POST.getlist('car-checkbox[]')
   print(cars)
```

Weirdly enough when i try to get the checked data, i keep getting [] value,
where did i miss ? am i misunderstand something?

P.S
i followed this post
[How to get array of values from checkbox form Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44628251/how-to-get-array-of-values-from-checkbox-form-django)

Comment: You should send checkbox values in ajax request `data` field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$('#submit-car').click(function () {
        const car_checkbox = [];
        const user_id = "Some test UserId";
        const csrftoken = "Provided CSRF TOKEN";
        $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
                car_checkbox.push($(this).val());
        });  //STore the checkbox result in an array

        const data = {"user_id": user_id, "car-checkbox": car_checkbox}
        console.log(data);

        $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/submit-car/',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#submit-form-field').prop('disabled', true);
            location.reload();
            alert("Submit OK!");
        }
    });
    
        
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-row">
    <input type="checkbox" name="car-checkbox" value="Audi" id="chck1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="car-checkbox" value="BMW" id="chck2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="car-checkbox" value="Lambo" id="chck2">
    <input id="submit-car" type="button" value="Submit">
</div>
```

So where you are sending the checkbox array value to backend /submit-car/ ?

what is `user_id` in your click evennt?

As you are using `jquery` so

```
$('#submit-car').click(function () {
    
    const car_checkbox = [];

    $("input[type=checkbox]:checked").each(function(){
          car_checkbox.push($(this).val());
    });  //STore the checkbox result in an array

    const data = {"user_id": user_id, "car-checkbox": car_checkbox}
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/submit-car/',
        data: data,
        beforeSend: function (request) {
            request.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#submit-form-field').prop('disabled', true);
            location.reload();
            alert("Submit OK!");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Your selector are not right which you are using to get checkbox values . Did you test that ?

Comment: No I didn't.. My point was he should pass the of checkbox in `jquery` that he is not doing.
`car-checkbox": car_checkbox`

Comment: and what's the problem with selector ? `"input:checkbox[name=type]:checked"` selecting based on tnput type is checkbox

Comment: Test it at your end and then let me know if that works  . But , anyways your answer is already accepted by op just one suggestion please test your code and  post it as answer so that it will be helpful for future readers .

Comment: Made the changes and tested.