# django one submit form several input same name

Tags: python, django, input

In a template i have one form with several inputs same name as in the example below.
(the name of the inputs is allways the same, but the value is different, for example rate in one case is 743.80 and in the other form 669.32).
I need to know how to post all the same name inputs without they repalce each other. In PHP I was using `name="rate[]"` and then for each, but i don´t have idea, how to make with it python/django.
Any idea?

```
<form method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="hotel" value="{{ hotel.id }}" >
    <input type="hidden" name="room" value="{{ room.id }}" >
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="1" >
    <input type="hidden" name="rate" value="743.80" >
    <select name="qty">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

    <input type="hidden" name="hotel" value="{{ hotel.id }}" >
    <input type="hidden" name="room" value="{{ room.id }}" >
    <input type="hidden" name="policy" value="1" >
    <input type="hidden" name="rate" value="669.32" >
    <select name="qty">
    <option value="0">0</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/formsets/) for this.

Comment: Daniel, please let me ask you a one last question, and thank you. This "forms" are made directly in the template, because the "inputs" hidden have to take the values that are rendered in the template. I can´t do this in view because the client have to select the qty in the form. Can i work with formset anyway?

Comment: Daniel, please let me a little help more, can i proceed this way?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Generally you shouldn't use hidden fields like this; if the data is supplied by the db in the first place, it should be added when the form is saved, not when it is rendered.

Comment: how can i do this, if the data that replace value of inputs is inside a loop in the template.

Comment: i have two type of rooms, and two rates for each room

Answer (score 4):

you can use `get_list` for example:

```
rates = request.POST.getlist('rate')
```

details here [QueryDict.getlist](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/request-response/#id1) search the description for QueryDict.getlist, and here [django-getlist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190070/django-getlist) humanly

Comment: Yes, i am trying to manage input groups(as if each block of code between hotel input and qty input were a separated form), if a use get list. i only obtanin the rates, but not inside a group. is it so?

Comment: yes, but if you take all parameters as list, they all will have the same sequence

Comment: as i know, yes, you need

Comment: One last question, i need to obtain a list for each block. for example [hotel = input hotel, room = input.room, rate = input.rate]. If the client select the qty in the other block i need to obtain a new list [hotel = input hotel, room = input.room, rate = input.rate]. Can i se getlist to this?

Comment: as Daniel say, you better use formset

Answer (score 0):

You're better off using AJAX, serializing your form and posting an array of objects that group the inputs together by section and not by input name. The method you're using now is prone to errors when mapping the form values on the backend since what you're trying to do would group values by name and not by their input groups.

Comment: thank you. I am looking obtain the result you describe(as if each block of code between hotel input and qty input were a separated form).  if i use get list. Would i get that result?