# Accessing list in request.get

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm having difficulties checking on the `request.GET` parameters in my Django template.

`django.template.context_processors.request` is enabled so I can access `request.GET`.

With the following GET parameters in my URL: `?floor=1&floor=2&building=1`, I'm trying to do something like the below:

```
{% if 1 in request.GET.floor %}IN{% else %}OUT{% endif %}
```

I would expect this to return `IN`. However, `OUT` is displayed.

When diving in more detail:

```
{{ request.GET }}
{{ request.GET.floor }}
{{ request.GET.urlencode }}
```

Following is returned:

```
<QueryDict: {'building': ['1'], 'floor': [1, 2]}>
2
building=1&floor=1&floor=2
```

So it looks like my list of `[1, 2]` for 'floor' is reduced to the last element ('2'). 
What's the best way to check on the full list?

Comment: Use `request.GET.getlist('floor')`. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190070/django-getlist.

Comment: @Bobort: that's in the view, any way to access in the template directly? I can pass `getlist('whatever')` to the context of course, but I have a dozen of these items.

Comment: Oh, I see.  You could create a templatetag/filter called `getlist` that takes the key as an argument.  Your current setup doesn't utilize anything related to getting the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a filter.

```
templatetags/getlist.py

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name="getlist")
def getlist(request_dictionary, key):
    return request_dictionary.getlist(key) if request_dictionary else []
```

In your template:

```
{% load getlist %}
{% if 1 in request.GET|getlist:'floor' %}IN{% else %}OUT{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the edits, SaeX!  I'm glad you were able to get it working!