# Send an array with ajax to my python function in django

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

I'm trying to send an array to my `python` function inside `views.py` but I can't. It always crash with a `keyError` because is not recognising the data from `js`.

**Code:**

Python function in views.py:

```
def cargar_datos_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        filtros = request.POST['node']
    print(filtros)
    ctx = {'A':filtros}
    return JsonResponse(ctx)
```

JS

```
var csrftoken = $("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
var frutas = ['Manzana', 'Banana'];
$.ajax({
    url: '/../../data_bbdd/',
    type: 'POST',
    headers:{"X-CSRFToken": csrftoken},
    data: {
        'node': frutas,
    },
    dataType: "json",
    cache: true,
    success: function(response) {
        coords = JSON.stringify(response.A);
        alert(coords);
    }
});
```

How can I send an array to my python function?

Thank you very much.

Comment: are you getting any error?
check in network, what data you're sending?

Comment: Post the error as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `node` is a list it will be posted as `node[]` by JQuery so you can get it using `request.POST['node[]']` or `request.POST.getlist('node[]')`

More informations on why this is the behavior of JQuery on this stackoverflow's answer :[django - getlist()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190070/django-getlist)