# Why is my multiple select form field only submitting one value Django?

Tags: python, django

Having trouble getting this form to submit/save multiple inputs from my multiple select form field...

```
def StaffHome(request):

dates = request.user.availability_set.all()
bookings = request.user.booking_set.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'remove' in request.POST:
        form = RemoveDate(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for d in form.cleaned_data['date']:
                for i in dates:
                    if d == str(i.dates):
                        i.delete()
                    return redirect('main-home')
    elif 'add' in request.POST:
        form = AddDate(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for d in form.cleaned_data['date']:
                Availability.objects.create(user=request.user, dates=d)
                return redirect('main-home')



context = {
    'today': datetime.datetime.now().date(),
    'bookings': bookings,
    'form': AddDate(request.user),
    'form2': RemoveDate(request.user),
    'dates': dates
}

return render(request, 'users/staffhome.html', context)
```

I tried using request.POST.getlist('date') but that was throwing a method object not subscriptable error.

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190070/django-getlist it looks like you need to use `request.POST.getlist('date[]')` for that method to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you returning at right place, please check.

```
def StaffHome(request):

dates = request.user.availability_set.all()
bookings = request.user.booking_set.all()

if request.method == 'POST':
    if 'remove' in request.POST:
        form = RemoveDate(request.user, request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            for d in form.cleaned_data['date']:
                for i in dates:
                    if d == str(i.dates):
                        i.delete()
             return redirect('main-home')
    elif 'add' in request.POST:
        form = AddDate(request.user, request.POST.getlist('add'))
        if form.is_valid():
            for d in form.cleaned_data['date']:
                Availability.objects.create(user=request.user, dates=d)
            return redirect('main-home')



context = {
    'today': datetime.datetime.now().date(),
    'bookings': bookings,
    'form': AddDate(request.user),
    'form2': RemoveDate(request.user),
    'dates': dates
}

return render(request, 'users/staffhome.html', context)
```